# Recursive Function to retrieve a deeply nested hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
ATTRIBUTES_TO_ANONYMIZE = [ { submitted_input: [:salutation, { user_location: [:city, :country, :full_address] }] }]

  def runner
    anonymize_data_hash(ATTRIBUTES_TO_ANONYMIZE)
  end

  def anonymize_data_hash(data, key=nil)
    if data.is_a?(Hash)
      data.each do |key, value|
        anonymize_data_hash(value, key)
      end
    elsif data.is_a?(Array)
      data.each do |value|
        anonymize_data_hash(value, key)
      end
    else
      puts "#{key}[#{data}]"
    end
  end
```

This generates the following output:

```
submitted_input[salutation]
user_location[city]
user_location[country]
user_location[full_address]
```

The output I really need is:

```
submitted_input[salutation]
submitted_input[user_location][city]
submitted_input[user_location][country]
submitted_input[user_location][full_address]
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve this output. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: FWIW, I have created the gem exactly to iterate deeply nested structures (including arrays.) A shameless plug: [`iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your recursive calls keep track of the nesting instead of just forwarding the key from the last hash.

```
  def anonymize_data_hash(data, path=[])
    if data.is_a?(Hash)
      data.each do |key, value|
        anonymize_data_hash(value, path + [key])
      end
    elsif data.is_a?(Array)
      data.each do |value|
        anonymize_data_hash(value, path)
      end
    else
      path = path.clone
      key = path.shift
      path = (path + [data]).map{|x| "[#{x}]"}.join
      puts "#{key}#{path}"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :-)

Comment: A follow up question: If I really want to call the hash values for the keys like that: send("#{key}")[path] that means ```submitted_input["salutation"]
submitted_input["user_location"]["city"]
submitted_input["user_location"]["country"]
submitted_input["user_location"]["full_address"]``` How could I achieve that?

Comment: Consider using a case statement here: `case data; when Hash;...;when Array;...else...`.